# Android/ Eclipse: how to avoid empty Logcat ? (Logcat bug)

Tags: debugging

I have every 15 minutes the problem of "blank logcat" or "logcat bug", tell it as you wish !

I know the following solutions to solve this issue:

- going to DDMS and selecting my device => 80% of the time, the logcat displays correctly what it has to display.
- 20% of the time, this is not sufficient, I have to restart Eclipse and...perahps the Logcat displays everything again.

I CANNOT BEAR THIS ISSUE ANYMORE !! Please, tell me if you have got a solution !!

Thanks.

Comment: Since this is an issue with a development tool, [so] is probably a better place for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the logcat in Eclipse, open a command prompt and run `adb logcat [your-filters-here]` from the platform-tools directory of the SDK. At least for me, this method works better.

Another thing that used to work for me is to press the "clear log" button in Eclipse's logcat window, then changing the logging level to something else and back. Not guaranteed to work always, but most of the time.